# MySQL Trigger: Before Insert or After Insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am working on some database project (PHP/MySQL) used for billing.

Whenever a new bill is created I want to generate a bill number consisting of year, week and increment number. I would like to do this with a trigger. The trigger will use the existing billnumbers to find the increment number or start with a fresh increment for the first bill n a new week and/or new year.

Apart from generating the bill number, I can do a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and set the `NEW.billnumber` to the newly generated billnumber. It is also possible to do an `AFTER INSERT` and update the record with the generated billnumber.

My question is which one should I choose. `BEFORE INSERT` or `AFTER INSERT`? I did search for this, but I can't find a good argumentation when to use BEFORE or AFTER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that it can be done with `BEFORE INSERT` only because MySQL does not allow manipulation of the table that triggered the `AFTER INSERT` trigger.